# Can't seem to place toggle correctly in side nav bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

[image]

First off, I want to move that 3 line toggle button to the right of the newsletter nav-link. This is showing for medium, and below, sized screens. On large screens, the side-nav links turn into normal nav-links. Code is provided later.

Then, [image]

I want the toggle button to turn into an 'X' button on the top right of the slide nav (where the 3 line toggle button would have been if the side-nav was hidden).

Here's what I have so far:

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse fixed-top" style="background:rgba(1,1,1,0);">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"><img style="height:75px; width: 75px;" class="logo img" src="{% static 'homepage/img/leaves.png' %}">COMPANY</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sideNav" aria-controls="sideNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <div class="frame" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                  <div class="bar1"></div>
                  <div class="bar2"></div>
                  <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
            </button>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#newsletterModal" class="nav-link " id="navlink">Newsletter</a>
                </li>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item {% if nbar == 'page' %}active{% endif %}">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'page' %}" id="navlink">page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item {% if nbar == 'about' %}active{% endif %}">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'about' %}" id="navlink">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item {% if nbar == 'login' %}active{% endif %}">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'login' %}" id="navlink">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <div class="hidden" id="sideNav">
                <ul class="navbar-side">
                    <li class="navbar-side-item">
                      <a class="side-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'page' %}">page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-side-item">
                      <a class="side-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'about' %}">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-side-item">
                      <a class="side-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-side-item">
                      <a class="side-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
hidden {
    display:none;
}

.navbar-side {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(66,67,68,1);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar-side-item {
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 5rem;
}

.side-link {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

Any ideas on fixes or where I can look to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following only addresses your first question because Stack Overflow rules don't allow answering/asking multiple unrelated questions in one. Instead, you are advised to post separate questions when the issues are so different from each other.

So, to solve the main problem of this question i.e. the problem related to the question title, you first place the newsletter link element *before* the toggler button in the HTML and then you use the `order` classes to reorder things like shown in the code snippet below.

The order classes you'll need there are:

- `order-lg-3` for the newsletter item
- `order-2` for the toggler and
- `order-last order-lg-2` for the main links group

`order-last` says: On the smallest screens, you shall appear last. And then `order-lg-2` says: but from the large (lg) screen size onwards you shall appear as number 2 in the order.

That setup works because the toggler button is automatically hidden on larger screens and because it appears between the newsletter link and the main link group in the HTML.

The order of items in the HTML is normally treated for determining the order of appearance *unless* the `order` classes kick in to change that.

Here's a working code snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page for testing):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img class="brand-icon mr-2" src="https://placehold.it/60" width="30" height="30" alt="">Company
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto order-lg-3 pr-3">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Newsletter</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="navbar-toggler order-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-last order-lg-2" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just edited my answer and code snippet to address an issue there was when clicking the hamburger button. Post a new, separate question for the other issue.